# why merge PR from github，but project Contributors not show correct?

Tags: android, git, github, open-source, pull-request

for example:

https://github.com/ParadiseHell/one/pull/1

this PR author is **punkisnotdead3**

but in the project page:

https://github.com/ParadiseHell/one

we can see Contributors is:

**punkisnotdead2**

why? this error can be fixed?

Comment: what does this have to do with stack overflow/android, seems like a question regarding github entirely ?

Answer (score 0):

The commit is written using @punkisnotdead2 from the device that's why it is added in the contributors .. if you want to keep use punkisnotdead3 change it from your device git configuration using

```
git config [--global] user.name "User name you want"
git config [--global] user.email "email you want to use"
```

Comment: thank u. but i want to know can i change the project contributors now?  or may be  it is too late?

Comment: I am not sure but you can search for Edit commit author after push